Quotient of a compact Hausdorff and totally disconnected topological group is totally disconnected
If $G$ is a topological group which is compact Hausdorff and totally disconnected, and $H$ is a normal and closed subgroup of $G$, then Weibel's book on homological algebra claims that $G/H$ is a totally disconnected space.
I have managed to prove that this is again a compact Hausdorff space, but the total disconnectedness seems to not work out. I have tried utilizing equivalent notions, such as that a compact Hausdorff space is totally disconnected if and only if it admits a base of clopen sets, but without success.
Some more properties that might be useful is that the quotient map $G \to G/H$ is open in this case, and that the connected component of an element $x$ in a compact Hausdorff space is the intersection of its clopen neighbourhoods.

If I recall correctly, since $H$ is closed, $G/H$ it $T_2$. Hence, the quotient map is closed-and-open (if your above statement is correct?). But zero-dimensionality is an invariant of closed-and-open maps, see Engelking, General Topology, Exercise 6.2.H.

A topological group is totally disconnected if and only if it has a basis at identity of open subgroups (maybe this requires compactness, I'm not sure right now).
Fix any open neighbourhood of identity in $G/H$. It is necessarily of the form $U/H$ for some open $U=UH$. Since $U$ is an open neighbourhood of the identity in $G$, it contains and open subgroup $V\leq G$. Since $H\unlhd G$, $VH\leq G$ is open, so $VH/H\leq G/H$ and its preimage is $VH$, so $VH/H$ is an open subgroup of $G/H$.
Since $V\subseteq U$, $VH\subseteq UH=U$, so $VH/H\subseteq U/H$.
